# gcc don't see standard header files

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I've got simple program in c++ which include two standard headers

stdio.h and iostream. When I type

```
gcc main.c
```

I got error: fatal error: iostream: There is no file or directory
even if I rewrite iostream to iostream.h
But when I type:

```
g++ main.c
```

everything works fine.
I have to fix this problem cause my IDE(CodeLite) probably use gcc command

Comment: Change the name of `main.c` to `main.cpp` so the C++ mode will be used by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how you'd compile a C source file. If you're compiling C++ rather than C, then

- rename the file extension to something GCC recognises as C++, such as `.cpp`, `.cxx` or `.cc`
- invoke the compiler as `g++` rather than `gcc`

Comment: @iwaszek12, there is another option. You can do `g++ -x c++ main.c`. This works the other way as well. If you want to use a .cpp extension as C you can do `g++ -x c main.cpp`.

Comment: @Zboson: Indeed, there are other ways fix the compiler's confusion; then you'd only be confusing humans, and perhaps other tools like source analysers. I wouldn't suggest that, since I don't generally hate humans, and try to write code for them as much as for the compiler.

Comment: I agree, the only time I have really used it is with http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ (an online compiler where you can actually set the g++ options) to force their compiler to compile as C. I also sometimes use it if I want to do a quick test if my code compiles in both C and C++ but I would not use it in general.